# Align link buttons at bottom of multiple divs

Tags: html, css

I am using a responsive-flex-grid layout with each "box" containing text and a button; with the boxes all being the same height.  I am trying to get the buttons to align at the bottom of the box (cognisant of the margins and padding) and with each other.

```
---------- ---------- ----------
| text   | | text   | | text   |
|        | | text   | | text   |
|        | |        | | text   |
|        | |        | |        |
| button | | button | | button |  buttons aligned with each other at bottom of box
---------- ---------- ----------
```

```css
.container {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 1170px;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.col {
  flex: 1 1 8%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 0 0 1em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.col:first-child { padding-left: 0; }
.col:last-child { padding-right: 0; }

.col-span-1 {
  flex-basis: 8.3333%;
}

article {
  height:100%;
  border:1px solid black;
  padding:1em;
}

a.quickbutton {
    color: #afafaf;
    background-color: #fafafa;
    background-image: none;
    border: 0 none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    font-size: larger;
    font-weight: 500;
    margin-bottom: 4px;
    padding: 1.5em;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    white-space: normal;
    max-width: 100%;
    text-decoration:none;
}

a.quickbutton:hover {
    background-color: #afafaf;
    color: #fafafa;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.bottom {
  
  /*--------------------------------*/
  /* THIS IS WHERE I NEED SOMETHING */
  /*--------------------------------*/
  
  /* vertical-align: bottom; doesn't work */
  
  /* position:relative: bottom:0px; doesn't work */
}


@media only screen and (max-width: 48em) {
  .col-span-1
  {
    flex-basis: 100%;
    padding:0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

    <div class="row">
    
        <div class="col col-span-1">
            <article>
                <h2>Article 1</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, at albucius nominavi mei. Dicant decore voluptatibus pro ei, eum aliquid eruditi mnesarchum id. Eam ad summo verterem vituperatoribus. Suscipit prodesset delicatissimi nam ei.</p>
                <a href="#" class="quickbutton bottom">Button 1</a>
            </article>
        </div><!-- col -->
        
     <div class="col col-span-1">
            <article>
                <h2>Article 2</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, at albucius nominavi mei. Dicant decore voluptatibus pro ei, eum aliquid eruditi mnesarchum id. Eam ad summo verterem vituperatoribus. Suscipit prodesset delicatissimi nam ei.</p>
                <p>Commodo alienum ne cum, recteque torquatos an eum. Ad mandamus sententiae intellegebat mei, cum ut nostrum propriae gubergren. Vocent albucius intellegebat vix ex. Cetero vocent aperiam sit ad. Meis tritani vel ex, ne qui admodum repudiandae, civibus lucilius perfecto in qui. Nam eu debet soleat facete. Pro an quod meis tollit, eu nam interesset appellantur, te partiendo erroribus interpretaris eos.</p>
                <a href="#" class="quickbutton bottom">Button 2</a>
            </article>
        </div><!-- col -->
        
     <div class="col col-span-1">
            <article>
                <h2>Article 3</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, at albucius nominavi mei. Dicant decore voluptatibus pro ei, eum aliquid eruditi mnesarchum id. Eam ad summo verterem vituperatoribus. Suscipit prodesset delicatissimi nam ei.</p>
                <p>Commodo alienum ne cum, recteque torquatos an eum. Ad mandamus sententiae intellegebat mei, cum ut nostrum propriae gubergren. Vocent albucius intellegebat vix ex. Cetero vocent aperiam sit ad. Meis tritani vel ex, ne qui admodum repudiandae, civibus lucilius perfecto in qui. Nam eu debet soleat facete. Pro an quod meis tollit, eu nam interesset appellantur, te partiendo erroribus interpretaris eos.</p>
                <p>Ei has movet liberavisse. Sed errem ridens singulis te, mea liber homero doctus te, ne oratio aliquip antiopam vis. In graecis incorrupte accommodare nam. No pri malorum euismod dissentiet, vix ut ludus sententiae intellegebat. Esse labitur voluptatibus sed no, posidonium temporibus an nec.</p>
                <a href="#" class="quickbutton bottom">Button 3</a>
            </article>
     </div><!-- col -->
       
    </div><!-- row -->

</div><!-- container -->
```

Of course, when viewed on a mobile device or small screen the boxes should "collapse" to their minimum required size.

I'd really appreciate some help in achieving this as it has been driving crazy!  If there are any other improvements, I'm willing to learn more.

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the solution in the snippet below

```css
.container {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 1170px;
}

.row {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.col {
    flex: 1 1 8%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 0 0 1em;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.col:first-child { padding-left: 0; }
.col:last-child { padding-right: 0; }

.col-span-1 {
    flex-basis: 8.3333%;
}

article {
    height: calc(100% - 100px - 2em);
    border:1px solid black;
    padding: 1em 1em calc(1em + 100px) 1em;
    position: relative;
}

a.quickbutton {
    color: #afafaf;
    background-color: #fafafa;
    background-image: none;
    border: 0 none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    font-size: larger;
    font-weight: 500;
    margin-bottom: 4px;
    padding: 1.5em;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    white-space: normal;
    max-width: 100%;
    text-decoration:none;
}

a.quickbutton:hover {
    background-color: #afafaf;
    color: #fafafa;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.bottom {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:1em;
    height: 100px;
    width: calc(100% - 2em);
}


@media only screen and (max-width: 48em) {
    .col-span-1
    {
        flex-basis: 100%;
        padding:0;
    }
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css">
    </head>
    <body>

    <div class="container">

        <div class="row">

            <div class="col col-span-1">
                <article>
                    <h2>Article 1</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, at albucius nominavi mei. Dicant decore voluptatibus pro ei, eum aliquid eruditi mnesarchum id. Eam ad summo verterem vituperatoribus. Suscipit prodesset delicatissimi nam ei.</p>
                    <div class="bottom"><a href="#" class="quickbutton">Button 1</a></div>
                </article>
            </div><!-- col -->

            <div class="col col-span-1">
                <article>
                    <h2>Article 2</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, at albucius nominavi mei. Dicant decore voluptatibus pro ei, eum aliquid eruditi mnesarchum id. Eam ad summo verterem vituperatoribus. Suscipit prodesset delicatissimi nam ei.</p>
                    <p>Commodo alienum ne cum, recteque torquatos an eum. Ad mandamus sententiae intellegebat mei, cum ut nostrum propriae gubergren. Vocent albucius intellegebat vix ex. Cetero vocent aperiam sit ad. Meis tritani vel ex, ne qui admodum repudiandae, civibus lucilius perfecto in qui. Nam eu debet soleat facete. Pro an quod meis tollit, eu nam interesset appellantur, te partiendo erroribus interpretaris eos.</p>
                    <div class="bottom"><a href="#" class="quickbutton">Button 2</a></div>
                </article>
            </div><!-- col -->

            <div class="col col-span-1">
                <article>
                    <h2>Article 3</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, at albucius nominavi mei. Dicant decore voluptatibus pro ei, eum aliquid eruditi mnesarchum id. Eam ad summo verterem vituperatoribus. Suscipit prodesset delicatissimi nam ei.</p>
                    <p>Commodo alienum ne cum, recteque torquatos an eum. Ad mandamus sententiae intellegebat mei, cum ut nostrum propriae gubergren. Vocent albucius intellegebat vix ex. Cetero vocent aperiam sit ad. Meis tritani vel ex, ne qui admodum repudiandae, civibus lucilius perfecto in qui. Nam eu debet soleat facete. Pro an quod meis tollit, eu nam interesset appellantur, te partiendo erroribus interpretaris eos.</p>
                    <p>Ei has movet liberavisse. Sed errem ridens singulis te, mea liber homero doctus te, ne oratio aliquip antiopam vis. In graecis incorrupte accommodare nam. No pri malorum euismod dissentiet, vix ut ludus sententiae intellegebat. Esse labitur voluptatibus sed no, posidonium temporibus an nec.</p>
                    <div class="bottom"><a href="#" class="quickbutton">Button 3</a></div>
                </article>
            </div><!-- col -->

        </div><!-- row -->

    </div><!-- container -->

    </body>
</html>
```